# OnUnload not working in chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-chrome, opera

I know there are many links regarding Onbeforeunload,BeforeUnload and Onunload events of JavaScript which have some cross browser problems. After going through, possibly, all the questions, I want to ask this again

> Is there any way so that onunload can work for Chrome and Opera?

I don't want to use onbeforeunload as it pops up before closing window.In my application user clicks a "Save And Exit" button after which an alert box is popped up showing "Your details are saved" with OK button. clicking on OK button redirects user to a new popup asking the window is about to close with yes and no buttons. onbeforeunload event as returns a string, hence it doesn't allow me to show the "AlertBox" asks for leave this page and stay on this page. which is not in alliance with my application requirement as i want as alert box. (working fine in IE, not working in Opera and chrome).
i am using unload and onbeforeunload events from code behind c#

Comment: And does it work in other browsers? It sounds like you're asking how to use a  custom alert instead of the native `onbeforeunload` box, and no browser supports that.

Comment: onbeforeunload is now supported in Opera 15 based on the WebKit engine but not in any prior versions based on Presto.

Comment: yep you are right, I want an custom alert box instead of onbeforeunload confirm Box. Its working in IE8, and safari. for Opera and Chrome it is not..Debugging shows that for both Chrome and Opera BrowserName is "Chrome", so fix for both will be same.

Comment: @Neel Its working but onbeforeunload  is not wat I want to use.. some Onunload kind of event ..